# Error in replacing current data in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to replace current data that i got from user in this table. But, instead of replacing the current data, it provide me the new row of data.

```
$scope.users = [{username: "a", name:"b", status:"0", scope:"1"}];

    $scope.addUser = function(user) {
        $dialog.open({
            showClose: false,
            closeByEscape: true,
            template: 'views/user/user-user-add.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function ($dialogScope) {
                $dialogScope.title = "New User";
                $dialogScope.user = {
                    username : "" ,
                    name : "",
                    status : "",
                    scope : "",
                    };
            if(user){
                $dialogScope.title = "Update User";
                $dialogScope.user = {
                    username :user.username ,
                    name :user.name ,
                    status : user.status,
                    scope : user.scope,
                    };
                    }

            $dialogScope.add = function() {
                $scope.users.push($dialogScope.user);
                $dialogScope.closeThisDialog();
                }
            }],
        });
    };
```

Comment: can you provide the frontend code, the dialog part.

Comment: @Nivesh provide u the plunker link.  https://plnkr.co/edit/VjUfWIaWxVduXNDT4zfR

Comment: hey, did not get you. You are performing addUser and `$scope.users.push` would certainly add a new user to your `users array` Now which data do you have to replace? The old one that you got from the users array displayed in the table. If yes, then it more sounds like update user than addUser.

Comment: i need to replace those data that user entered. that is why i used if(user) { $dialogScope.user ={ username: username ...}} . now the problem is that, the data doesnt change in table @Nivesh

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code...

```
$dialogScope.user = {
    username: user.username ,
    name: user.name ,
    status: user.status,
    scope: user.scope,
};
```

...is creating a `user` object on the scope. Then this code...

```
$scope.users.push($dialogScope.user);
```

...is pushing a reference to that object onto your `users` array. Now any time you later modify `$dialogScope.user` you are modifying that reference that you pushed to your `users` array instead of creating a new `user`. What you should do is this...

```
$scope.users.push(angular.copy($dialogScope.user));
```

...to create a new `user` instance and push that onto your `users` array. Then you can clear out the values for your dialog using...

```
$dialogScope.user = {};
```